# Storing queues in a database

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a set of resources and I want to have a FIFO queue for each resource so when a task comes, it executes in the order. Is it possible to store all the queues in a single table or should I have a different table for each queue? Each resource may or may not have any items in the queue.

Comment: Why no use Oracle's Advanced Queuing: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28420/aq_opers.htm

Answer (score 0):

Just Use Identity column in this way you can track which resource came first and you can perform the requested operation on the resource in the order of insertion.

Regards

Ashutosh Arya

Comment: There is no "identity" column in Oracle.

Comment: task comes in the queue and uses the resource resource.

Comment: Use a sequence to generate the values to be inserted into the table; a sequence is roughly the Oracle equivalent of an identity column (yes, quite rough).

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use create queue table. And use DBMS_AQADM package for enqueue and dequeue that data.

But you need to create different queue for each table.